# How to change default size of the comment boxes

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2011

It's incredibly frustrating to resize the box every time I put a comment. Anybody know the shortcut, or can provide a clue so I can script this?

Comment: There's [this](http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/09/11/format-comment-box/) link, but I'm not sure by what you mean by "comment boxes"

Answer (score 2):

I use this VBA macro to mass-resize comments when its necessary. As far as I know, you cannot change the default size of comment boxes.

I played with the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event to trigger the resizing macro automatically, but that's a terrible idea when it comes to sorting/moving large ranges.

```
Sub AutoFitComments()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each MyComment In ActiveSheet.Comments
        With MyComment
            .Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
            .Shape.Top = .Parent.Top + 3
            .Shape.Left = .Parent.Offset(0, 1).Left + 3
            .Shape.Placement = xlMove
        End With
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Insert the code in your workbook's VBA editor. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> »
<kbd>Enter</kbd> to run the macro quickly.

[image][image]